# UICollectionView and access UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I create customised `UICollectionViewCell` as follow.

1. Go to File -> New -> File -> User Interface -> Empty -> Call this
   nib "customNib".
2. In customNib, drag a `UICollectionViewCell` in.

   Give it reuse cell identifier `@"Cell"`.

   Inside Cell, `UILabel is inserted to label the cell`.
3. `File -> New -> File -> Cocoa Touch Class -> Class named
   "CustomCollectionViewCell" subclass of UICollectionViewCell.`
4. Go back to the custom nib, click cell and make a link to this custom
   class `CustomCollectionViewCell`.

   Insert outlet of `UILabel` as
   `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellText;` in `CustomCollectionViewCell.h`.

So `CustomCollectionViewCell.h` class has

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellText;


@end
```

5. Go to `viewDidLoad` of ViewController and insert

Code:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"customNib" bundle:nil];
 [_collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

6. Then in

Code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   //here i need to access cell's UILabel to write text    

}
```

At step 6, I need to label the cell using the inserted `UILabel`.
How can I access the `UILabel` inside the cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast your dequeued cell to your custom class by replacing:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = 
    [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" 
                                              forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

with:

```
CustomCell *cell = 
    (CustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" 
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then you should be able to access your label.